# The animation wouldn't stop after mouse click (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with this one? JS newbie here.
I can't stop h1 moving with the click. It just starts moving twice slow after the click.
I have tried also to do it through jQuery, but it didn't work either.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Interactive Programming</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Hello,world!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var leftOffset = 0;
    var topOffset = 0;
    var moveHeading = function() {
      $("#heading").offset({
        left: leftOffset,
        top: topOffset
      });
      if (leftOffset < 200 && topOffset == 0) {
        leftOffset++;
      } else if (leftOffset == 200 && topOffset < 200) {
        topOffset++;
        leftOffset = 200;
      } else if (topOffset == 200 && leftOffset > 0) {
        leftOffset--
      } else if (leftOffset == 0 && topOffset > 0) {
        topOffset--;
      }


    };
    setInterval(moveHeading, 30);

    var heading = document.getElementById("heading");
    var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, 30);
    var stopMovement = function() {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
    heading.addEventListener("click", stopMovement);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so your h1 animating from left to right and back? why you dont use @keyframes?

Comment: You're calling `setInterval` twice, and not storing the first `intervalId`, so it keeps moving.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Amy!

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I love removing code to solve problems. In this case, removing the first call to `setInterval(moveHeading, 30)` resolves the problem. It's being called twice. Just leaving `var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, 30);` makes it work ok.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Interactive Programming</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Hello,world!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var leftOffset = 0;
    var topOffset = 0;
    var moveHeading = function() {
      $("#heading").offset({
        left: leftOffset,
        top: topOffset
      });
      if (leftOffset < 200 && topOffset == 0) {
        leftOffset++;
      } else if (leftOffset == 200 && topOffset < 200) {
        topOffset++;
        leftOffset = 200;
      } else if (topOffset == 200 && leftOffset > 0) {
        leftOffset--
      } else if (leftOffset == 0 && topOffset > 0) {
        topOffset--;
      }


    };
    var heading = document.getElementById("heading");
    var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, 30);
    var stopMovement = function() {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
    heading.addEventListener("click", stopMovement);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Viktoriia great! Please accept my answer or the other answer. ✅

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with:

```
setInterval(moveHeading, 30);
```

You later on in your code set this equal to `intervalId`:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, 30);
```

And so, your `clearInterval` will only stop the interval `intervalId`, but it will not stop your first interval, and thus your heading keeps moving.

See working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Interactive Programming</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Hello,world!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var leftOffset = 0;
    var topOffset = 0;
    var moveHeading = function() {
      $("#heading").offset({
        left: leftOffset,
        top: topOffset
      });
      if (leftOffset < 200 && topOffset == 0) {
        leftOffset++;
      } else if (leftOffset == 200 && topOffset < 200) {
        topOffset++;
        leftOffset = 200;
      } else if (topOffset == 200 && leftOffset > 0) {
        leftOffset--
      } else if (leftOffset == 0 && topOffset > 0) {
        topOffset--;
      }


    };
    // Remove this: setInterval(moveHeading, 30);

    var heading = document.getElementById("heading");
    var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, 15);
    var stopMovement = function() {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
    heading.addEventListener("click", stopMovement);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note**: You will notice that the speed of the movement is now slower, this is because you are only moving your fewer times (as you only have one interval now). You can change the interval gap to be 30/2 = 15 to get the original speed back: `var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, 15);`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Nick!

Comment: @Viktoriia no worries :)